# Refreshing Materialzed View in Oracle

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

I have created materialized view (MV) on a table which is updated once in a month..
Do we have any automatic way to refresh my MV...
I mean how refresh of MV is done is it manual or 
Automatic how frequent we can do????
like can i use Trigger for it..??

I am using Oracle9i on PL/SQL developer
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refresh the view manually if you want

```
execute DBMS_SNAPSHOT.REFRESH( 'MAT_VIEW','OPTION');
```

Where the OPTION parameter could be

F, f    Fast Refresh
C, c    Complete Refresh
A   Always perform complete refresh
?   Use the default option

The automatic refresh rate are supplied when you create the materialized view

```
    CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MAT_VIEW
    REFRESH FAST START WITH SYSDATE 
    NEXT  SYSDATE + TIME_INTERVAL -- 
    WITH PRIMARY KEY 
    AS SELECT * FROM TABLE;
```

Remember to create a log for the table if FAST START are used.

I recomend you the following link about Materialized View. It has a lot of info about this topic: http://www.dba-oracle.com/art_9i_mv.htm

Comment: @jonathan & Eugen thanks.... what is fast refresh and compelte refresh?? and if i write trigger i will write this execute statement inside it with complete refresh..correct me if i am wrong..

Comment: @Avi rou're right, you can put it on a trigger or you can even configure the MV to be refreshed automatically when commit (See the link). Fast refresh means that the view will be refreshed incrementally, using the info stored in a log. It will help to improve the performance in large views or in frequently refreshed ones.